# 2 passports,2 different names, not OK dual citizenship

Tags: customs-and-immigration

Hi in [case 4 of dual citizenship](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/52100/i-have-two-passports-nationalities-how-do-i-use-them-when-i-travel) (2 passports,2 different names, not OK dual citizenship). My question is why bother to make all the detour through country C when I can reserve a flight from A  to to C  by transit connection at B  and by arriving at B  not head to the transit connections but instead to the exit with my B passport. Ofcourse I never fly to C and I only make the reservation so that the airline in A  country lets me board the plane to B since I don't have a visa for B country (but I have their passport which they don't know!)
.  Sorry for the duplicate moderators but I cannot comment !

Comment: You probably could, except that for countries which discourage or prohibit dual citizenship, such an itinerary either does not exist or would be far more expensive.

Comment: @MichaelHampton we're talking passport fraud here. He's probably already in violation of several laws in one or either of the countries he's holding passports of and by traveling like this he'd be entering a country on false premises and probably leaving one with false identification as well.

Comment: Imagine this: after being arrested for the hideous crime of trying to enter my home country B through the official point of entry at B and with the aid of my government issued passport B under my official legal name B,

Comment: I end up in the dark dungeons of the B country. I hold up on the breaking wheel long enough as to make this convincing and I finally confess that I was doctored to this horrible crime by a nefarious person on internet under the code name jwenting . Swiftly a joint task force is assembled from CIA, DEA, FBI, Delta Force , IBM, GSM, DDT, ThD etc, etc and under careful examination of your IP's and writing pattern your true identity is established ,then one night they caught you by surprise in your room torturing your own flesh.

Answer (score 4):

The specifics will depend on the countries involved but in most cases this is a really BAD idea.

Here is what probably going to happen

1. You leave countryA with passportA and nameA pretending to go to C
2. You have a transit in countryB. You abandon your flight and enter countryB with passportB using nameB.
3. The airline will cancel the remainder of your ticket including your return flight (if there is any)
4. If you have any luggage that's checked through to country C you will loose this too
5. The airline will report to countryB that nameA did not board and has therefore illegally entered countryB. At this point you (under nameA) have committed a serious crime and are wanted as a an illegal immigrant in countryB
6. The airline may report this back to countryA as well. Now you are potentially a criminal or at least "subject of interest" in countryA as well.

Stating the obvious: For most countries these would constitute serious legal offenses and can get you into serious trouble. Don't break the law. If you need to travel between country A and B then you need to abandon one of your citizenships.

Comment: For number 3 yes the airline will cancel the rest of the ticket , yes one pays a litlle bit more but doesn't make the unnecessary round about. I cannot think of a discrete way notifying the airline about change of plans :) For number 4 luggage? what luggage? I never wrote anything about luggage and it's obvious that all the methods written under case 4 can only be done WITHOUT luggage. Now the only really question remains 5  that is if somebody can remain indefinitely in transit area of the airport as depicted in the movies ...

Comment: @joeblasco the most and only important parts are the crimes you'd be guilty of by what you're planning to do. It constitutes passport fraud in both departure and arrival destinations, as well as breach of contract with the airline(s) involved. Quick way to lose your freedom, your money, and end up on a bunch of no-fly lists and terrorist watch lists.